# What is difference between layout-small and layout-sw320dp

Tags: android

I know how to use the following folders but for example I do not know what is difference between `layout-small` and `layout-sw320dp`?

Also, Suggest for me that which the folders are important to optimization.I do not like my program be seen for users as irregular.I want a final answer from you.

Based on which the folders I design my layouts? Because I have not multiple android devices to test the layout in different screen size.

I know how to use the folders and I have not problem about it.but my question is which the folders for continuous use and for all devices?

```
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp


layout-small,
layout-large etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are qualifiers to define layouts for specific screen sizes.

*Before* Honeycomb - 3.0 (I guess), the screen's diagonal size was measured based in 4 groups: *small, normal, large, and extra-large*.

*After* that layout resources are defined for screen sizes with the *smallest width* (**sw** stands for smallest width).

Resuming, `layout-small` is **deprecated** and `layout-swXXXdp` qualifier should be used instead.

You can get more info about these qualifiers in [Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)'s Android official doc page.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the qualifiers -small, -normal, -large had been marked as deprecated in API 13. Now the recommended way to go is using the -swdp folder structure. (see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support )

The number of resources folders in your project depends basically on the type of devices you're targeting at (small phones, phablets, tablets, ...) and the number of *different* layouts you want to maintain. In most cases implementing a layout for landscape/portrait modes for phones and for tablets should be enough. Though you can create another layout for a specific screen size if you really need it.

Hope this helps.